# Rotating a sprite towards a point and move it towards it with a duration

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touch

So if i have something like:

```
class game: SKScene {
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sprite")
}
```

How do I make a point/sprite/shape that it will first rotate towards and then move towards it (not TO it) with a duration of 1 second.

Comment: if you want it to move towards, and not to, then you use moveBy. not moveTo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the following code

Let's define your sprite and destination point

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mario.png")
let destPoint = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
```

Now let's define 2 vectors. The first one (`v1`) is a vertical vector. The second one (`v2`) represents the delta space from your sprite and your destination point

```
let v1 = CGVector(dx:0, dy:1)
let v2 = CGVector(dx:destPoint.x - sprite.position.x, dy: destPoint.y - sprite.position.y)
```

Now I calculate the angle between these 2 vectors

```
let angle = atan2(v2.dy, v2.dx) - atan2(v1.dy, v1.dx)
```

and assign it to the sprite

```
sprite.zRotation = angle
```

### Extension

I encapsulated the code inside an extension

```
extension SKNode {
    func rotateVersus(destPoint: CGPoint) {
        let v1 = CGVector(dx:0, dy:1)
        let v2 = CGVector(dx:destPoint.x - position.x, dy: destPoint.y - position.y)
        let angle = atan2(v2.dy, v2.dx) - atan2(v1.dy, v1.dx)
        zRotation = angle
    }
}
```

So now you can do

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mario.png")
sprite.rotateVersus(CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10))
```

[image]

### Rotation + Move Extension

For the rotation animation followed by the move animation you can use this extension

```
extension SKNode {
    func rotateVersus(destPoint: CGPoint, durationRotation: NSTimeInterval, durationMove: NSTimeInterval) {
        let v1 = CGVector(dx:0, dy:1)
        let v2 = CGVector(dx:destPoint.x - position.x, dy: destPoint.y - position.y)
        let angle = atan2(v2.dy, v2.dx) - atan2(v1.dy, v1.dx)

        let rotate = SKAction.rotateToAngle(angle, duration: durationRotation)
        let move = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: v2.dx * 0.9, dy: v2.dy * 0.9), duration: durationMove)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([rotate, move])
        self.runAction(sequence)
    }
}
```

> Thanks to Wikipedia for the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros.#/media/File:Super_Mario_Bros._box.png).

Comment: You only answer half the question here

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: Updated!

Comment: Is there a way to make it change the direction of the rotation, so if it has to rotate 359 degrees, it wouldn't spin 359 degrees clockwise, but 1 degree counter clockwise?

Comment: @Asphys: Yes, just use `SKAction.rotateToAngle(angle, duration: durationRotation, shortestUnitArc: true)`

Comment: Hey i noticed that it doesn't move with a constant speed, so if i click further, it will move further and faster, but if i click near where the sprite will spawn, it will go slower. Is there a way to rotate and move the sprite with a constant speed, rather than duration?

Comment: @Asphys: It all depends on the `duration` params. E.g. if you specify 3 secs as duration and the destination point is near, it will go slow. If the distance if greater it will go faster because the duration is always 3 secs. So if you want constant speed you need to change the duration accordingly.  I hope I made myself clear